# Oracle file with .BAK extension

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have received 10 backup files from the client with the extension .bak. Now, the person from the client side who created those backup files left and no one knows what kind of bak file that is.
I tried identifying the file type by looking at the metadata using various tools with no success.

We tried restoring it using on SQL server, however, we were unable to restore it. The client thinks it can be an oracle backup taken using RMAN.

Can please someone confirm if an oracle backup can be taken with .BAK extension? If yes, how can I restore it? I am no good in using RMAN or sql plus

A step by step guidance would be help

Thanks!

Comment: It could be anything.  If the "client" that provided it doesn't even know what it is, then how would you/they/us/anyone even be expected to recognize a situation where the file might be useful?  What is your relationship with the "client" - your responsibility for backing up and recovering anything?  Why isn't this documented?

Comment: Could you post the first 200 bytes of the files in hex and ascii? They might give a clue. Without logging of the backup process you will need some luck.

Comment: Ask someone who know Oracle and tell him please rman> catalog start with '<path of backup>'; - If they are Oracle backup then Rman will recognize them and using some command: rman> list backup of spfile; rman> list backup of controlfile; rman> list backup of database .... But easies way is to hire 3rd Oracle service do it for you. Oracle is much more complicated than SQL Server (using GUI attach - detach) indeed! It can take you week if have knowledge about oracle backup/restore!

Answer (score 0):

In rman backups the filenames hardly have any meaning. There is only one way to know what they really are and that is the logging of the backup process.

If this really are rman backup files, you could try to catalog them against a mounted database. That would be my first step.

If this succeeds you can try to struggle ahead. Some knowledge of oracle rman and ofcourse creating, backing up and restoring them using rman certainly helps. SQL server knowledge won’t be of much help at all.

If the files are catalogued, next step would be to restore the control file and the spfile. With those you should be able to create a useable instance that can restore the database.

This post could give some guidance in the catalog process: https://ittutorial.org/rman-catalog-start-with-command-tips-in-oracle/amp/

This assumes Linux but the same applies to windows. It helps if you know from what platform the database came since cross platform restores are an other story.